# use perl's qx{} / `...` operator with a list of arguments

Tags: perl, backticks, qx

`system`, `exec`, `open '|-'`, `open2`, etc. all allow me to specify the command to run as a list of arguments that will be passed directly to `execvp` instead of run through a shell.

Even if `perl` is smart enough to run it directly if it looks like a "simple" command, that saves me the trouble of correctly shell-escaping the arguments with all the nasty pitfalls that it entails.

Example:

```
open my $out, '|-', $prog, @args;
system $prog, @args;
exec $prog, @args;
```

instead of

```
open my $out, "|$prog @args";
system "$prog @args";
exec "$prog @args";
```

Is there such an equivalent for the `qx//` operator? Or do you have to always do it by hand eg.

```
sub slurpcmd {
   open my $h, '-|', @_ or die "open $_[0]|: $!";
   local $/ unless wantarray;
   <$h>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that (unfortunately) this wasn't an overlook from my part -- the only solution really is to do it with `open -|` or use one of the external modules listed in the other answers.

The backtick [implementation](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/refs/heads/blead:/pp_sys.c#l281) (whether invoked by `qx/.../`, `` `...` ``, or `readpipe`) is deep down hardwired to accept a single string argument:

```
PP(pp_backtick)
{
    dSP; dTARGET;
    PerlIO *fp;
    const char * const tmps = POPpconstx;
    const U8 gimme = GIMME_V;
    const char *mode = "r";

    TAINT_PROPER("``");
    if (PL_op->op_private & OPpOPEN_IN_RAW)
        mode = "rb";
    else if (PL_op->op_private & OPpOPEN_IN_CRLF)
        mode = "rt";
    fp = PerlProc_popen(tmps, mode);
    ...
```

Notice the `POPpconstx` which pops a single argument from the stack and the use of `PerlProc_popen` instead of `PerlProc_popen_list`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187828/discussion-on-answer-by-ccru-use-perls-qx-operator-with-a-list-of). Please [edit] the answer to incorporate any relevant information from the chat discussion.

Answer (score 5):

A list form of the qx operator is provided by the module [IPC::System::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple) as the function `capturex` (additionally like the other functions in that module, it will throw an exception if there is an execution error or non-zero response code, which you can tweak). Alternatively, you can use [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) to wrap a core `system` call and provide the same behavior, but it also has other functions that can wrap STDERR together or separately from STDOUT.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::System::Simple 'capturex';
my $output = capturex $prog, @args;

use Capture::Tiny 'capture_stdout';
my ($output, $exit) = capture_stdout { system $prog, @args };
# standard system() error checking required here
```

In core the pipe open is for the most part the only option, aside from [IPC::Open3](https://perldoc.pl/IPC::Open3) which is similarly complex but allows directing STDERR as well.

Comment: those modules are not part of the standard distribution, right?

Comment: @Căcărău IPC::System::Simple and Capture::Tiny are not core, but they are pure-perl so they can be [fatpacked](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker) into a script.

Comment: @zdim It is functionally identical to qx except for the method in which it takes arguments and its additional error handling. Not to imply that it's another built-in operator, since it clearly isn't.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few simple options.

- [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote) + `qx`:

  ```
  use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
  my $cmd = shell_quote(@cmd);
  my $output = `$cmd`;
  ```
- [IPC::System::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple):

  ```
  use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );
  my $output = capturex(@cmd)
  ```
- [IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3):

  ```
  use IPC::Run3 qw( run3 );
  run3(\@cmd, \undef, \my $output);
  ```
- [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run):

  ```
  use IPC::Run qw( run );
  run(\@cmd, \undef, \my $output);
  ```

The first solution involves a shell, but none of the others.